# Get the session by ID in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, session

In a controller in MVC 3. I have

```
 Session.Add("FacilityID", facility.FirstOrDefault().Name);
```

Now in a web form, I want to use it.

```
var x = "this session"; // how to? Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you want to do something with the FacilityID in your web form:

```
var x = Session["FacilityID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

then you can access as easy as:

```
var x = Session.Add["FacilityID"];
```

Comment: typo ;)  answer is quite easy so